# How do I choose the default guest session?

Tags: 11.04, gdm, session

My computer has an ATI card, which supports 3D, but doesn't refresh the screen properly.
This is because I use the classic session on 11.04 instead of Unity. That's OK.

But when I start a **Guest Session**, the Unity-based session starts automatically, because this are the default settings for new users.

So, **is there any way to change the session to start by default?**
(So the classical GNOME desktop gets launched instead of Unity)

Comment: @people who answered: All the answers are great, so I'm not sure which one to accept. I think I will accept Marky's. **Thanks for answering!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the default is done through **Login Screen Settings**. At the bottom there is a drop-down list that lets you set the default. I'm not sure if this affects guest sessions too. Let me try it out and I'll update this post.

*edit: Yeah it changes the guest session too. I guess it would've been obvious since you need to unlock it with admin privs. For some reason it doesn't work until a restart though.*

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to change your `~/.dmrc` file to:

```
[Desktop]  
Session=gnome
```

This will change your personal account's default session.

If you want to change the default for the guest session, you should try to change the file
`/usr/share/xsessions/guest-restricted.desktop` to:

```
Exec=/usr/share/gdm/guest-session/Xsession gnome-session --session=gnome
```

Comment: Not saying that the above is wrong but this doesn't work for me. I instead edited /usr/share/xsessions/guest-restricted.desktop. In the said file, change the value of Exec to: /usr/share/gdm/guest-session/Xsession gnome-session --session=gnome

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. You were referring to the guest session ;-) I just saw it and edited my anwser.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mv /usr/share/xsessions/guest-restricted.desktop /usr/share/xsessions/guest-restricted-old.desktop
sudo ln -s /usr/share/xsessions/gnome-2d.desktop /usr/share/xsessions/guest-restricted.desktop
```

Comment: **Welcome to AskUbuntu!** +1 Good catch, vito.